# ArrayAdapter showing Error: Tabbed Activity and ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-tabbed-activity

I am trying to create a Tabbed Activity which contains a List. I have created the Tabbed Activity and I want to create the list in the fragment. Each List Item contains 2 ImageViews and 4 TextViews. Therefore, I created a custom Class and a Custom ArrayAdapter. Here is the Code -

1. Coins.java - This is the fragment of the tabbed Activity.

   ```
   package com.example.android.cotescol;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   public class Coins extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currency_list, container, false);

           final ArrayList<CoinObject> coins = new ArrayList<Currency>();

           coins.add(new CoinObject(1, "India", 1947));
           coins.add(new CoinObject(1, "India", 1947));

           CoinAdapter itemsAdapter = new CoinAdapter(this, coins);
           ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
           listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

           return rootView;
       }
   }
   ```
2. CoinObject.java - It is a custom class in which each object contains all the details of the coin.

   ```
   package com.example.android.cotescol;

   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Locale;
   import java.util.Map;

   public class CoinObject {

       private final static int NO_IMAGE_AVAILABLE = R.drawable.nia;
       private final static String NOT_AVAILABLE = "Material Not Specified";
       private final static double NOT_KNOWN = 0.00;

       private int denomination;
       private String country;
       private String countryCode;
       private int year;
       private int obverseImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_AVAILABLE;
       private int reverseImageResourceId = NO_IMAGE_AVAILABLE;
       private String material = NOT_AVAILABLE;
       private double diameter = NOT_KNOWN;
       private double weight = NOT_KNOWN;
       private double thickness = NOT_KNOWN;
       private double value = NOT_KNOWN;

       public CoinObject(int denomination, String country, int year, int obverseImageResourceId, int reverseImageResourceId , double diameter, double thickness, String material, double weight, double value) {
           this.denomination = denomination;
           this.country = country;
           this.year = year;
           this.obverseImageResourceId = obverseImageResourceId;
           this.reverseImageResourceId = reverseImageResourceId;
           this.diameter = diameter;
           this.thickness = thickness;
           this.material = material;
           this.weight = weight;
           this.value = value;
           this.countryCode = getCountryCode(country);
       }

       public CoinObject(int denomination, String country, int year, double diameter, double thickness, String material, double weight, double value) {
           this.denomination = denomination;
           this.country = country;
           this.year = year;
           this.diameter = diameter;
           this.thickness = thickness;
           this.material = material;
           this.weight = weight;
           this.value = value;
           this.countryCode = getCountryCode(country);
       }

       public CoinObject(int denomination, String country, int year) {
           this.denomination = denomination;
           this.country = country;
           this.year = year;
           this.countryCode = getCountryCode(country);
       }

       public String getCountryCode(String countryName) {
           // Get all country codes in a string array.
           String[] isoCountryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
           Map<String, String> countryMap = new HashMap<>();
           // Iterate through all country codes:
           for (String code : isoCountryCodes) {
               // Create a locale using each country code
               Locale locale = new Locale("", code);
               // Get country name for each code.
               String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
               // Map all country names and codes in key - value pairs.
               countryMap.put(name, code);
           }
           // Get the country code for the given country name using the map.
           // Here you will need some validation or better yet
           // a list of countries to give to user to choose from.
           String countryCode = countryMap.get(countryName); // "NL" for Netherlands.  

           return countryCode;
       }

       public int getDenomination() { return denomination; }
       public int getYear() { return year; }
       public int getObverseImageResourceId() { return obverseImageResourceId; }
       public int getReverseImageResourceId() { return reverseImageResourceId; }
       public double getDiameter() { return diameter; }
       public double getWeight() { return weight; }
       public double getThickness() { return thickness; }
       public double getValue() { return value; }
       public String getCountry() { return country; }
       public String getCountryCode() { return countryCode; }
       public String getMaterial() { return material; }
   }
   ```
3. CoinAdapter.java - It is a custom ArrayAdapter

   ```
   package com.example.android.cotescol;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class CoinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CoinObject>{
       public CoinAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CoinObject> currencies) {
           super(context, 0, currencies);
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           View listItemView = convertView;
           if (listItemView == null) {
               listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
           }

           CoinObject currentCoinObject = getItem(position);

           TextView denominationTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.denomination_text_view);
           denominationTextView.setText(currentCoinObject.getDenomination());

           TextView countryTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.country_text_view);
           countryTextView.setText(currentCoinObject.getCountry() + "(" + currentCoinObject.getCountryCode() + ")");

           TextView yearTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.year_text_view);
           yearTextView.setText(currentCoinObject.getYear());

           ImageView obverseImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.obverse_image_view);
           obverseImageView.setImageResource(currentCoinObject.getObverseImageResourceId());

           ImageView reverseImageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.reverse_image_view);
           reverseImageView.setImageResource(currentCoinObject.getReverseImageResourceId());

           return listItemView;
       }
   }
   ```

In the Coins.java file, I am getting an error while creating an Instance of the CoinAdapter class. Also the findViewById() is shown in red. [Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFl2c.png)

It would be really helpful if someone guided me to do it the correct way. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
CoinAdapter itemsAdapter = new CoinAdapter(this, coins);
```

With:

```
CoinAdapter itemsAdapter = new CoinAdapter(getActivity(), coins);
```

Replace:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

With:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```